# How can I edit certain configurations on IIS Configuration editor using powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am currently working on a very small project, and one of the things I'm trying to accomplish using powershell is enabling kerberos authentication and SSO service on an IIS website(for demonstration im using the default website on IIS).

I have figured out how to do most steps using powershell, but in order to complete the job I need to edit the configuration editor on the path: `"system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication"`. More specifically, I need to change the setting there of useAppPoolCredentials from false to true.

I am trying to achieve this using powershell, but my knowledge is pretty limited and I can't manage doing it. [image]

Anyone has an idea of how I do that?

Comment: Click Help to learn how to use Generate Script, then you won’t need to ask similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it and wanted to share my solution:

```
Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $ConfigSection -AttributeName "useAppPoolCredentials" -AttributeValue "True"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
  Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication"
-name enabled -value true -PSPath "IIS:\" -location $siteName
```

Comment: No, it won't work... I'm not trying to enable windows authentication, I'm trying to edit a certain configuration after I've already enabled windows authentication on the iis site.